# Which is the best algorithm for implementing Image Processing functionality(edge detection algorithm)?

Tags: image, image-processing

I need to implement the edge detection program in C#. Can anyone help me out which is the best algorithm to look out for the optimum result.

As I gone through Laplacian Gaussian, Sobel, Canny, Prewitt algorithms, but not able to decide which is the best on every image. As every algorithm is best in some cases. Now I do have a requirenment to use all in one algorithm.

So is anyone have an idea about any other algorithms or the way of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

i'd say laplace with prewitt and sobel as far as I know you need to implement a way to check vertically and horizontally with the laplace algorithm, with the matrix

```
-1 -1 -1
-1 8 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

it's done automatically